# How to pass an array into laravel json?

Tags: json, laravel, api, parameter-passing, response

Here my simple code..

```
 $country=['Bangladesh','Pakistan'];
    $capital=['Dhaka','Islamabad'];
    return response()->json([
        'country'=>$country,
        'roll'=>$roll,
    ]);
```

If i run the above code ,the output will be like below..

```
{
"country": [
    "Bangladesh",
    "Pakistan"
],
"roll": [
    'Dhaka',
    'Islamabad'
]
```

}

But I want that my expected output will be like ..
EDIT: Following JSON is invalid (2 same key country)

```
{ 
{
   "country":"Bangladesh",
   "capital":"Dhaka"
},
{
   "country":"Pakistan",
   "capital":"Islamabad"
},
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```php
$countries = ['India', 'Bangladesh', 'Pakistan'];
$capital = ['Delhi', 'Dhaka', 'Islamabad'];
$response = [];
foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
    $response[$key] = [
        'country' => $country,
        'capital' => $capital[$key],
    ];
}
return response()->json($response);
```

it will return

```json
[{
        "country": "India",
        "capital": "Delhi"
    },
    {
        "country": "Bangladesh",
        "capital": "Dhaka"
    },
    {
        "country": "Pakistan",
        "capital": "Islamabad"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is wrong. You simply cant have 2 same keys (`country`) in output json. You should have country and capital encapsulated in separate {}.